# Проблема при выводе массива, заполненного рандомными числами - Java

Tags: java

Всем привет, написал программу которая должна заполнять массив рандомными числами и выводить его
на экран, как итог в консоле вообще ничего не появляется, буду рад за помощь
Вот код:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TablicaLiczb tablicaLiczb = new TablicaLiczb(5);
        tablicaLiczb.do_tablicy();
        tablicaLiczb.wypisz();
    }
}
```

```
public class TablicaLiczb {
    private int liczbaElementow;
    private int[] tablica = new int[liczbaElementow];
    private int max = 0;
    private int min = 0;

    public TablicaLiczb(int liczbaElementow) {
        this.liczbaElementow = liczbaElementow;
    }

    public int random(int max, int min) {
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
        max -= min;
        return (int) (Math.random() * ++max) + min;
    }

    public void do_tablicy() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tablica.length; i++)
            tablica[i] = random(1, 1000);
    }

    public void wypisz() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tablica.length; i++)
            System.out.print("\t" + tablica[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну ок, не выводится. А что уже пробовал, чтобы выяснить почему не выводится? Как сам пытался решить проблему?

Comment: Семь раз компилировал программу, я не знаю как в таком случае искать проблему, так как в консоле даже ошибок нету никаких

Comment: Ну например, вывести в консоль tablica  и посмотреть, заполняется ли и чем. Базовые то способы поиска ошибок нужно знать. Я уж не говорю про пошаговое выполнение в дебагере...

Comment: Поэтому я выше и написал, что не знаю как искать ошибки в таком случае

Comment: И + в методе ```wypisz``` я и пытаюсь вывести эту таблицу, но она не выводиться, именно поэтому я и хотел получить подсказки, а не оскорбления

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, как работает инициализация полей в java.

```
    private int liczbaElementow;
    private int[] tablica = new int[liczbaElementow];
```

Это кусок кода выше, будет выполнен до того, как вызовется конструктор. Причем `liczbaElementow` будет проинициализированна значение по-умолчанию для данного типа, т.е. для `int` это `0`. А значит `tablica` - будет пустым массивом.

То что потом в конструкторе передается новое значение и `liczbaElementow` заново иницилизируется уже никак не повлияет на `tablica`. Ну и далее в `do_tablicy` цикл будет исполнен `0` раз.

Исправить нужно путем переноса иницилизации в конструктор:

```
    private int liczbaElementow;
    private int[] tablica;
    private int max = 0;
    private int min = 0;

    public TablicaLiczb(int liczbaElementow) {
        this.liczbaElementow = liczbaElementow;
        this.tablica = new int[liczbaElementow];
    }
```